# bin/dev restarting after ctrl+c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I am using a project based on [Bullet Train](https://github.com/bullet-train-co/bullet_train). Bullet train is based on Ruby on Rails

It's Procfile.dev file looks like this

```bash
web: bin/rails server -p 3000
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -t 25
js: yarn build --watch
light-js: yarn light:build --watch
light-css: yarn light:build:css --watch
light-mailer-css: yarn light:build:mailer:css --watch
```

So when I run `bin/dev` starts ok. Whenever I need to make a change, I hit Ctrl+C, but instead of just shutting down, it shuts down and starts again, only after the second Ctrl+C the script stops.

Any ideas on what could be causing the restart?

Answer (score 0):

Add  `config.assets.debug = true` on development.rb file.